# Perl's "make_path" and "remove_tree" give different results with an empty options hash

Tags: perl, path, mkdir

I have a line of code in my module that looks exactly like this:

```
make_path($root_dir);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't create the desired directory (I have checked, and do have permissions there).

However, if I change it to the following:

```
make_path($root_dir, {});
```

It works fine. A couple lines earlier, I'm getting the same odd behaviour with `make_path($root_dir);` vs `make_path($root_dir, {});`. Any ideas why this could be?

I'm using perl 5, version 16, and File:Path version 2.09.

Comment: Seems odd. Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://sscce.org/)? What exactly is `$root_dir`? Is anything being printed to stderr?

Comment: Good plan @rutter. I actually just solved it. `$root_dir` is a `Path::Class::Dir`, so `make_path` must be converting it to a scalar at a different time when there's a config hash or something. passing in `"$root_dir"` works. I'll post a proper answer when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path::Class::Dir class creates hash-based objects.

`make_path`'s usage is `make_path(PATHS, OPTIONS_HASH)`.

When you pass a Path::Class::Dir object as `make_path`'s last argument, it's taken as the options hash.

You can work around this by explicitly providing an options hash

```
make_path($path, {})
```

or by explicitly stringifying the path

```
make_path("$path")
```